# Variable amount of params express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to define a route in express js that takes an unknown amount N of parameters. It should match the following routes, *capturing* all digit groups:

/scope

/scope/1/12

/scope/1/12/123

etc.

I wrote a regex for the matching of the n-amount of numbers, as follows:

```
/(?:\/?(\d+)\/?)/g
```

The global /g however doesn't seem to be allowed, see ([The regex parser of express js on github](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L505)). Am I doing something wrong here? I could solve this very ugly and dirty by doing something like:

```
^\/scope\/?(\d+)?\/?(\d+)?\/?(\d+)?
```

But this is not dynamic, feels dirty and if I add deeper levels of scoping I always will need to add more /?(\d+) regex parts, which is a model that does not fit my business logic. I am shure there must be a better way...

Okay, after a discussion with @vks, which was useful but unfortunately not answering the question, we came to the conclusion that this is not a regex problem. With the \g modifier a regex capturing all digit groups can quite easily be written, even in javascripts very limited regex engine.

The question now becomes more clearly formulated: since expressjs does not allow a full regex from begin to end, but rather encloses the regex you use in a route in it's own begin and end of a regex, not allowing /g modifiers, what is the expressjs idiomatic way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
^\/scope(?:\/\d+)*$
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/30

Comment: The problem with this is that it matches only the last parameter. https://regex101.com/r/eI9pV0/1 (see matches in the right corner)

Comment: I am sorry, the matches are indeed correct. Problem is the *capturing* of the digit groups. In expressjs, as far as I understand this, you need al parameters to be in () capture groups. (Also, if you see the github link provided, I am affraid I can't set the global flag)

Comment: The regex works and does what it needs to do. But have a look at the github link, I can't use a global flag...

Comment: @Quant does your engine support `\G` or `\K` flag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67109/discussion-between-quant-and-vks).